# How to see CrashLoopBackOff logs in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have an error in 1 of my docker container that makes a CrashLoopBackOff.

The same code work on the localhost so I guess its something to do with the env.

the problem is I can't manage to see any logs.

I have tried with

```
kubetail mypod

kubectl logs mypod

kubtctl logs --previous mypod
```

are there any more methods I can try in order to see what's the problem?

Comment: try to run docker image only

Answer (score 0):

try describing pod using following command:

```
kubectl describe pod <pod-name> -n <namespace-name>
```

I am suspecting it might have to do something with your readiness/liveness probes.

You can also check events in namespace using:

```
kubectl get events -n <namespace-name>
```